# Angular Reactive Forms: How do I use Form Group/Control within custom Components?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form defined this way inside an Angular Component:

```
filterForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    year: [''],
    needsSignature: [],
    deadlineAtRange: this.fb.group({
        from: [''],
        to: ['']
    }),
    signedAtRange: this.fb.group({
        from: [''],
        to: ['']
    })
});
```

I need to be able to pick 4 dates here (`deadlineAtRange.from`, `deadlineAtRange.to`, `signedAtRange.from` and `signedAtRange.to`), so I want to componentize the input that will be used for that.

The form, initially, looked this way:

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
    ...

    <div formGroupName="deadlineAtRange">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <label>Deadline from</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="from"
            [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YY', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' }"
            bsDatepicker
        >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <label>Deadline to</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="to"
            [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YY', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' }"
            bsDatepicker
        >
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
</form>
```

What I have done so far, is to create the following date picker custom component:

**datepicker.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sc-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './sc-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sc-datepicker.component.css']
})
export class ScDatepickerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() formControlName: string;

  bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bsConfig = {
      dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue'
    };
  }

}
```

**datepicker.component.html:**

```
<label>{{ label }}</label>
<input
  type="text"
  formControlName="formControlName"
  [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
  bsDatepicker
>
```

and used it inside the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
        ...

    <div formGroupName="deadlineAtRange">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <app-sc-datepicker
                [label]="'Deadline from'"
                [formControlName]="from"
            >
            </app-sc-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <app-sc-datepicker
                [label]="'Deadline to'"
                [formControlName]="to"
            >
            </app-sc-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
</form>
```

But there's no way I get the value of any date to update on the `filterForm`, and I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'deadlineAtRange -> '

Comment: where do you set the formControlName in your ScDatepickerComponent? there is only `@Input() label: string;` and in the template formControlName is hardcoded as "formControlName"

Comment: You would also need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` in your date picker component to actually connect it to a form.

Comment: @Sepultura you are right! That's a mistake I made when writing the post, the `@Input() formControlName: string;` was meant to be there too as it is in the original code. I just updated the post.